# Scipy calculate of multinomial coefficents

Tags: python, scipy

Short version:
Title kind of says it all.

Log Version:

I'm calculating multinomial coefficents for the first few elements in. Looking at a [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem), the math is fairly simple.

```
N! / (k1! * k2! * ....)
```

For mediums sized N the numbers get fairly silly quickly if you just brute force it. For example,

```
500!/ (495! * 4! * 1!)
```

has 500! in it, and `math.log(factorial(500), 10) ~= 1134` when the expression reduces too:

```
500!/ (495! * 4! * 1!) = 500 * 499 * 498 * 497 * 496 / 24
```

I tried playing with [scipy.misc.comb](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html#scipy.misc.comb), which works great for binomial. For my use case k1 is much larger then ki (i != 1), so I could calculate the binomial coefficient and then convert that to the corresponding multinomial coefficient, but that seems a little round about.

I assume there is a much better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered on the math stackexchange, and looks reasonable.

I think what the original answer is doing is just enumerating all the terms and cancelling, then computing the final result.  So sort of 1-step removed from the brute force, but doesn't look like it overflows.

Maybe this is the same as computing the bionomial coefficients.  Anyway there is also a logarithm algorithm cited there that I didn't comprehend at first glance.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204085/how-do-i-compute-multinomials-efficiently